# How to make SCons update installed files inside a directory that have changed?

Tags: scons

I'm doing:

```
data = env.InstallAs('$PREFIX/share/odysi', 'data')
env.Alias('install', data)
```

Which works fine the first time.  But if I change something inside the 'data' folder and do `scons -Q install` again, it says ``install' is up to date.` even though a file has changed and needs to be reinstalled.

There are a lot of files in the directory (and sub directories) so if I can avoid explicitly listing them, that would be best.  Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
files = Glob('data/*.*')
data = env.Install('$PREFIX/share/odysi', files)
env.Alias('install', data)
```

It needs at least SCons 1.0.1 for Glob support.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing, but to recursively include sub-directories and their files as well?

Comment: No. You would have to do a Glob-per-directory.

Comment: What if the sub-directories are dynamic and can't be known until the install step?

Comment: That's a pretty complex use case. Glob knows about generated Nodes so should do the right thing, but you'd probably have to write code to create dynamic Glob()s.